# Order of timestamps in requestAnimationFrame and mouse events

Tags: javascript, html, timestamp, requestanimationframe, mousedown

I ran into a problem where timestamps received in `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks and mouse events do not seem to be in order, I mean I expect them to be increasing (as I hope that time goes only in one direction :)), but that doesn't seem to be the case. It can be illustrated by this example code:

```
<html><body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let lastTimesamp = -1;

    function log(name, timestamp) {
        console.log(name, timestamp);
        console.assert(lastTimesamp < timestamp, "Invalid time", lastTimesamp, timestamp);      
        lastTimesamp = timestamp;
    }   

    function update(timestamp) {
        log("update", timestamp);

        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(update);

    function mouseDown(event) {
        log("mouseDown", event.timeStamp);
    }

    document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);  
</script>

</body></html>
```

If you start clicking with your mouse you can see this sort of output eventually:

[image: console log output]

which implies that mouse-down event happened before the last `update` call.

I get the opposite situation on my production app: call to `update` is made with a timestamp which is before the last call to mouse-down callback.

*Can someone explain it to me?* From the documentation it looks like they are not necessary measured in the same way, but wouldn't it make sense to time them in the same time?

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is that the AnimationFrameCallbacks queue has an [higher priority](https://github.com/WICG/main-thread-scheduling/blob/master/PrioritizedPostTask.md#existing-priorities) than UI events.

So it may occur that your UI event fires in the same frame than the painting frame, it will thus get its `timeStamp` set at this moment, or [even by the OS when it received it in the first place](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-inner-event-creation-steps%E2%91%A1). But, the UA will chose to prioritize the *AnimationFrameCallbacks* instead of the UI event callbacks, so the UI event callback will get delayed until the next event-loop iteration.

Since the rAF callback gets its own timestamp [from inside the event-loop iteration that will call it](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:current-high-resolution-time-2), this timestamp will be higher than the one of UI event, even though its callback fires before.

Also note that [Chrome has it's `requestAnimationFrame` method completely broken](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1018120), so it may not help for debugging.